# Integrate jBPM with Node.js and PostgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jbpm

I am about to start working on a system in Node.js and PostgreSQL. The system involves BPM. I have been looking for information but I have not found anything about if jBPM can be integrated in the system that I mentioned before. Please if you know something tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jBPM (and KIE in general) exposes a collection of rest APIs that would allow you to integrate your node application by calling those APIs and displaying or managing the process/rules data as needed. If you have jBPM installed you can see the Swagger documentation for the available APIs at the `/docs` endpoint on your installation.

The APIs can also be used to interact with other installed elements in your KIE process server.